# How to serve compressed Angular 2 bundles from AWS Cloudfront

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, compression, angular-cli, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to have AWS Cloudfront (with compression enabled) compress the bundle.js files generated by Angular CLI but Cloudfront does not compress the files.

Angular CLI does not generate .gz files so I upload the uncompressed bundle file to AWS S3 and then use Cloudfront to serve the files.
As per Cloudfront documentation, I'm not sure how to make Angular CLI inject content-length headers in the bundle files (if that's the issue)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manualy compress the files to gzip and upload to S3, defining Content-Encoding headers. CloudFront will do it automatically, if you enable serving gzip for the respective CloudFront Origin Behavior.

Check [CloudFront Serving Compressed Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html) for more information.